# Prior Art: Search Resources

Tags: patents, prior-art

I have searched for prior art in PubWest and patents.google.com.   In addition I have searched the web (Google) for any prior art that would invalidate a patent for my die.  That being said, is there any other resource that I should be searching to find prior art?  Clarification or requests to clarify the question are appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many patent applications do not publish until 18 months after they are filed, but can be used as prior art as of their filing date. Therefore, it's not possible to find all the potential prior art that could be used against an application (assuming it hasn't been filed yet, or was filed in the last 18 months).

Further, even if all the potential prior art were already public, it isn't especially practical to go through all of it. It sounds as if you've put in a good effort looking for prior art already. At this point, it may be best to file the application and see what the Examiner finds.

Also, remember that if you do turn up any prior art that's material to your patent application, you are obligated to disclose it to the USPTO.